# Using ternary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter way to write this?

```
var ttt = "dd";
if (ttt.length < 3) 
ttt= "i" + ttt;
```

Comment: It would pay to note that all the answers here are longer and less obvious than the original code. While it can be done, I definitely wouldn't suggest you do (for the sake of those reading the code later).

Comment: @Aidan: i cannot see how "var ttt="idd";" is longer and less obvious... .

Comment: @davyM... I'll give you that one but only on a literal level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours is pretty short, but if you want to use the the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator) (a.k.a the ternary operator), you could do the following:

```
var ttt = "dd";
ttt = ttt.length < 3 ? "i" + ttt : ttt;
```

... or if bytes are really precious (code golfing?), you could also do something like this:

```
var ttt = "dd".length < 3 ? "i" + "dd" : "dd";
```

... but then that could be reduced to just:

```
var ttt = "idd";
```

... as [@Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) suggested in a comment below.

Comment: +1 - I dunno though....`var ttt = "idd";` seems *pretty* short ;) Also, you need quotes around the `i` to be 100% on this one ;)

Comment: @Nick Fixed: Thought it was a variable at first.

Comment: A+++++++ would do business again

Answer (score 2):

The shortest with the same result is:

`var ttt="idd";`

because "dd" has a length of 2. so the if is always true and you'll always prepend "i"

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a regex:

```
var ttt = "dd".replace(/^(\w?\w?)$/, 'i$1');
```

But then you have 2 problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Or :

```
var ttt = "dd";
ttt = (ttt.length < 3 ? i : "") + ttt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also there's a way with && operator instead of `if`

```
var ttt = "dd";
ttt.length < 3 && (ttt = "i" + ttt);
```